# Macbook Pro 15" vs Macbook Pro 14"

Tags: laptop

I need to grab a device real quick and my two current options are:

Macbook Pro 15" early 2011
i7/8gb of RAM/ssd

Macbook Pro 14" late 2013 retina
i5/4gb of RAM/ssd

The work I need to be doing is Photoshop and Sketch (moslty android design stuff)

My question is will I suffer greatly if I do get the 2013 model? I know its 1333 RAM and that I can't upgrade it, but retina is nice and port layout suits me much better. Would photoshop/sketch/OS lag terribly with less RAM?

Thanks

Comment: Ummm there is no 14" MBP. Do you mean 13"? Personally, I'd recommend the 2011 (upgradability, i7 multi-threading, larger screen)

Comment: I agree with @NoahL. Lack of upgradeability really sucks. Great marketing ploy, though.

Comment: Thanks! Considering I plan on using it for just a few months? Not upgrading it or making it my daily driver.

Comment: Also yeah 13" my bad :D

Answer (score 3):

It's basically a choice of High perf + upgradability VS portable new machine.

The 2013 macbook is not upgradable but is equipped with a hi-res screen.

The 2011 however is equipped with a quad core CPU (8 Threads) which will perform way better in photoshop than the ULV CPU of the 2013 MBP. Moreover, the ram is upgradable, and the screen resolution is not that low (1400x900 or 1680x1050).

I personally think that the 2011 MBP is a proper machine that will suit better your needs.